# $.each on Enum JQuery

Tags: jquery, enums, each

I have an Enum defined in my Javascript like below:

```
BankTypesEnum = {
        'Savings': '0',
        'HomeLoan': '1',
        'Current': '2',
       'salary': '3'
    }
```

I want to run `$.each()` on this and compare with values from some other data source. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$.each(BankTypesEnum , function(key, value) { 
  alert(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

edit this code with your needs, instead of alert put compare or anything else you need to do with keys and values

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Searching for this since morning. Many thanks 'divide by zero'. You should be 'multiplied by 100' actually! :)

Comment: I would also like to here from you on this 'divide by zero': I am curious to know which one should be preferred? The one with Javascript or JQuery...in terms of speed? or will they be same as Enum is smaller here?

Comment: use `.each` because the code is more elegant. I don't think there will be any speed difference in both approaches, because `enum` is very small object.
Also you do the mess with approach by defining another variable and then iterating, why should you? My example works without redefining and this should save user memory, since JS /jQuery are client side scripts.

Comment: ok. From the answers by Mrinal and you, I don't know in general, but I am concluding $.each() for my particular scenario. As (1) I am already having JQuery library included in page so no explicit requirement; and (2) No performance difference as Enum is small; so the deciding point comes which is the memory space getting saved for that variable in  $.each() approach. Both the answers are correct though. Thank you guys for your time and answers!

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary for you to use $.each()? If looping through them is the purpose, you can simply use for for in loop like this:

```
var earnings=BankTypesEnum;
for(var myEarnings in earnings)
{
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mrinal.This is also working! Even though my purpose is served, I am curious to know which one should be preferred? The one with Javascript or JQuery...in terms of speed? or will they be same as Enum is smaller here?

Comment: see the basic difference b/w them is that it uses pure js and $.each will use jquery. nothing else. So if you are including jquery only for using $.each, i would recommend the above method. jquery simplifies a lot of things but comes with a little overhead. Pure js will always be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
BankTypesEnum = {
    Savings: 0,
    HomeLoan: 1,
    Current: 2,
    salary: 3
}

$.each(BankTypesEnum, function(i, data) {
    console.log(i + ' - ' + data)
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3veS/1/)